# Access aws s3 public bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to download data from one of Amazon's public buckets.
[Here is a description of the bucket in question](http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/)

The bucket has web accessible folders for [example](http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/index.html).
I would want to download say all the listed files in that folder.
There will a long list of suitable tiles identified, and the goal would be to get all files in a folder in one go rather than downloading each individually from the http site.

From other StackOverflow questions I realize I need to use the REST endpoint and use a tool like the AWS CLI or Cyberduck, but I cannot get these to work as yet.

I think the issue may be authentication. I don't have an AWS account, and I was hoping to stick with guest / anonymous access.
Does anyone have a good solution / tool to traverse a public bucket and grab the contents as a guest? Could a different approach using curl or wget work for this type of task?

Thanks.

Comment: Note... [we don't entertain](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "is there a tool for..." questions at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the AWS CLI, you need to provide the `--no-sign-request` flag to skip signing. Example:

```
> aws s3 ls landsat-pds
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
> aws s3 ls landsat-pds --no-sign-request
                           PRE L8/
                           PRE landsat-pds_stats/
                           PRE runs/
                           PRE tarq/
                           PRE tarq_corrupt/
                           PRE test/
2015-01-28 10:13:53      23764 index.html
2015-04-14 10:43:22         25 robots.txt
2016-07-13 12:53:31         38 run_info.json
2016-07-13 12:53:30   23971821 scene_list.gz
```

To download that entire bucket into a directory, you would do something like this:

```
> mkdir landsat-pds
> aws s3 sync s3://landsat-pds landsat-pds --no-sign-request
```

Answer (score 0):

- I kept getting

```
SSL validation failed for https://s3bucket.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

- To go around I use  `--no-verify-ssl` so then

```
aws s3 ls s3bucket --no-sign-request --no-verify-ssl
```

... does the trick